# How to change the backgroundcolour using binding under specific conditions

Tags: silverlight, binding

I need to change the background colour of a datagridrow, if a specific flag is true in the viewmodel.  If the flag is false, then leave it alone.

Is there something like "conditional binding" that would help in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a common requirement to convert a boolean to one of two instances of some arbitary type.

Personally I think this is the best tool for the job:  [Generic Bool To Value Converter](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/28/a-generic-boolean-value-converter.aspx) (but there may be some bias in that opinion)

Place an instance of the provided  converter in your UserControl's resources:-

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
     <local:BoolToBrushConverter x:Key="Highlighter" FalseValue="White" TrueValue="Yellow" />
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

Now you can apply this converter to a binding the ties a boolean value from the ViewModel to a property of type `Brush`.

However you have a bigger problem, how do you apply this converter to an individual data row?  The `DataGrid` does not directly allow you set a binding that is set on each row.

Assuming you're not a "no code in the view", you can do this with another static resource to hold a simple `Binding` then use the data grids `LoadingRow` event to apply it to each row that gets loaded.

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
     <local:BoolToBrushConverter x:Key="Highlighter" FalseValue="White" TrueValue="Yellow" />
     <Binding x:Key="RowBackgroundBinding" Path="yourBoolProperty" Converter="{StaticResource Highlighter}" />
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

On the DataGrid:-

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dg" LoadingRow="dg_LoadingRow" ...>
```

Then in code-behind:-

```
    private void dg_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.SetBinding(DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty, (Binding)Resources["RowBackgroundBinding"]);
    }
```

This will set up the binding on each row as it loads.

Comment: The link to your Generic Bool To Value Converter returned 500 - Internal server error.   Howerver I was able to find at: http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/28.aspx  and it's works as advertised.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that we've found correct answer on this question, but if it satisfies querist needs that's good. I only advice wrap this code in action, for instance ApplyBindingToDataGridRowAction with Binding property, and invoke this action on LoadingRow of DataGrid. That permit to avoid of accessing to binding resource by Key. Why do I think that we've not fount right answer? Do all as described above and than change in ViewModel boolean property of any item. Color of the row for this item doesn't change...

Comment: @Ralph:  I suspect the server was having a bit of a wobble at the time but the link is fine.  Glad you found it anyway.

Comment: @Vladimir: You are correct, the row does not update its background color. I'd be interested to see a full implementation of your interaction trigger approach. It'll be a seriously hefty piece of Xaml and it may fall foul of the same issue. The code above is definitely updating the Background when the view model property is changed but for some reason this is not reflected in the actual UI.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Later I will add a sample of the action wrapper of your solution and you can sure in readability of this declaration. Also I think that this question very interesting, thanks a lot for the author, and I want to look for the answer "how to make that row color will always update on viewmodel property changing". I have idea to try attach to each row dataTrigger which changes background. But in this case we should describe prototype for this trigger and clone it for each row. Later I will write about results of my investigation.

Comment: I've added full implementation of interaction trigger

Answer (score 3):

You can bind through a ValueConverter:

```
.... BackgroundColor="{Binding BooleanFlag, Converter=BoolToColorConverter}" ....
```

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) has more information but your Converter will be something like the following pseudo code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is boolean)
    {
         return (value as boolean) ? Color.Red : Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

You don't need to implement a `ConvertBack` method as it's a one way binding.

You will need to raise a property changed event when `BooleanFlag` changes.

Comment: The actual problem is wider than this.  How is this binding assigned to the `DataGridRow` instances so that it is sensitive to each `DataContext` for each row?

Comment: It should be returning SolidColorBrush not just a color

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, approach to solve this problem using IValueConverter is correct and I often use it.
But in your case I propose to use only **declarative approach**, because additional converters are additional abstraction in your solution and to understand this logic other programmer must overlook 2 files: declarative and converter implementation. And the colors, which will be switched, are identified in converter :( but not in declarative part.
To avoid this, use Microsoft.Expression.Interactions and System.Windows.Interactivity from Blend SDK.
Sample code:

> < Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

```
    < i:Interaction.Triggers>
        < c:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BooleanFlagFromViewModel}" Comparison="Equal" Value="True">
            < c:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="LayoutRoot" PropertyName="Background" Value="#345678" />
        < /c:DataTrigger>
    < /i:Interaction.Triggers>
< /Grid>
```

Hope it helps! Good luck!

**Update**

As I write in comment to AnthonyWJones to avoid of accessing to binding resource by Key, I advice to use TriggerAction.

1) TriggerAction code:

> [ContentProperty("Binding")]
>
> ```
> public class ApplyBindingToDataGridRowAction : TriggerAction<DataGrid>
> {
>
>     protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
>     {
>         DataGridRowEventArgs e = (DataGridRowEventArgs) parameter;
>         e.Row.SetBinding(DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty, Binding);
>     }
>
>     public Binding Binding { get; set; }
> }
> ```

2) Use in XAML:

> < DataGrid ...>
>
> < i:Interaction.Triggers>
>
> ```
>     < i:EventTrigger EventName="LoadingRow">
>          < a:ApplyBindingToDataGridRowAction>
>               < Binding Path="Is" Converter="{StaticResource Highlighter}"/>
>          < /a:ApplyBindingToDataGridRowAction>
>     < /i:EventTrigger>
> < /i:Interaction.Triggers>
> ```
>
> < /DataGrid>

Comment: I don't agree that an additional converter represents an "additional abstraction" (see my converter in my answer).  Its hardly rocket science to see what it does and there is no need to inspect its code to determine its intent.  In addition I echo my comment to ChrisF, this can't be applied to DataGridRows very easily.

Comment: I don't beleive DataTriggers are available with the Silverlight version.  Certainly it doesn't show up in the the intellisense.  Perhaps I'm using the wrong namespace? (clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions)

Comment: This functionality really available in silverlight 4. You can add  Microsoft.Expression.Interactions and System.Windows.Interactivity assemblies to your project. Describe namespace as you write above xmlns:core="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions". And in XAML - "core:" 
intellisence work fine

Comment: You would need to first in install Blend or the Blend SDK to have those assemblies available, they don't come with SL4 SDK as standard.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem using [DataTriggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx), changing the style when your binding is a certain condition.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Oops.  Which part doesn't work in Silverlight?  The DataTrigger or changing the style with one?

Comment: The only trigger supported in Silverlight is the Loaded event trigger.